# basis for a subspace system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, invariant-subspace

Given the system of equations:

$
x - y + 2z = 0 \\\\
x + 2y - z = 0
$

Using RREF yields the basis to the solution:

z*$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\\\1\\\\1\end{bmatrix}$

However if you set the equations to the following:

x = y - 2z

y = z

(follows from equation 1 replacing x in equation 2) -> the basis for this solution set is 2-dimensional with the following vectors:

$ y*\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\\\ 0 \\\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \And \ z*\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\\\ 1 \\\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

This basis is independent and 2-dimensional, but is there anyway to get to the 1 dimensional basis from this set of 2 vectors, namely (1,0,0) and (-2,1,1)?

Comment: I don't follow your second method. How did you arrive at these vectors? Note that neither satisfies the original system of equations.

Comment: the second method simply sets x = y - 2z and then replaces x in the 2nd equation resulting in: y - 2z + 2y  -z = 0 --> implies y = z

Comment: That makes sense, and should keep the same solution space. What I don't understand, though, is how these two new equations yielded these two new basis vectors. Neither of them satisfy the first equation, so I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: Well i simply just took the coefficients and put them into vector form with vectors y and z, but thinking about this some more y is not an independent vector since it's a scalar multiple of z and so it can't form part of the basis.

Comment: I think I understand about 50% now, thank you. When looking at a linear equation $ax + by + cz = 0$, there's a vector of coefficients $(a, b, c)$, and a solution set (vectors $(x, y, z)$ that, when substituted into the equation, produce $0$, e.g. $(c, 0, -a)$). Geometrically, the solution set is the plane, and the vector of coefficients is the normal direction. You seem to be mixing these up somewhat. Remember, when solving equations, you should always be able to substitute the result back into the original equations, and have them be satisfied.

Comment: OK, so B having to be in the column space of the set S of vectors means all points in B have to be points on a plane and cannot be vectors themselves

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what you're asking here. My points are: 1. Don't confuse vectors of coefficients and vector solutions to equations, and 2. check your solution by substituting back into the original equations. If you follow the second rule in particular, you should be ok.